# What part of the sdf file is sdf::ElementPtr in the load() function?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Suppose we have a Sdf file .world, like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">

    <model name="my_velodyne">
      <include>
        <uri>model://velodyne_hdl32</uri>
      </include>

      <!-- Attach the plugin to this model -->
      <plugin name="velodyne_control" filename="libvelodyne_plugin.so">
        <velocity>25</velocity> 
      </plugin>
    </model>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

When the load() function is called, for example:

```
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>

namespace gazebo
{
  class VelodynePlugin : public ModelPlugin
  {
    /// \brief Constructor
    public: VelodynePlugin() {}

    public: virtual void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
    }
};

  // Tell Gazebo about this plugin, so that Gazebo can call Load on this plugin.
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(VelodynePlugin)
}
```

What part of the Sdf file is `sdf::ElementPtr _sdf`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16467/what-part-of-the-sdf-file-is-sdf::elementptr-in-the-load()-function?/) by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe `_sdf` is the `<plugin>...</plugin>` element. It helps plugins load parameters from the SDF file. The [Random Velocity Plugin tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_random_velocity&cat=) has some code that makes use of the `sdf::ElementPtr`.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on 2017-06-20**:
Thanks sloretz!